# GetLastError() Returns 'ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES' (18) after attempting to create a registry key

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following code, attempting to allow the program to run at startup:

```
HKEY key;
    if(RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,LPCWSTR("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"),&key) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout<<"Unable to open Reg key last error - "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";
        system("pause");
    }
```

Omitting the parts that aren't necessary. It prints that there was an error creating the registry key with the error code 18, which according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) means that I'm encountering an error that returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`. Unfortunately the description says the same thing and I don't know what this means in the case of creating a registry key. I have tried running the program as an administrator, **the key does not already exist either.** Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it states:

Return value

"If the function succeeds, the return value is ERROR_SUCCESS.
**If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h.** You can use the FormatMessage function with the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM flag to get a generic description of the error."

It does not state to call GetLastError().  Also, this has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: 1) This has to do with C++, not sure if you read the OP 'bout that. 2) The gerneric gescription is the same as the enum value, just without underscores as explained in the link I posted. Not that helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Your error checking is wrong. Registry API functions return error codes. They don't use `SetLastError`. You have to use the error code returned by the function to diagnose errors.

The obvious error in your code is the cast to wide text. That does not change the fact that your string is actually 8 bit text. Use the `L` prefix.

```
L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"
```

For what it is worth, you should use `RegOpenKeyEx` to open keys rather than `RegOpenKey`. And for creating keys use `RegCreateKeyEx`.

Comment: Every statement in this answer is informative and important.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same result (`GetLastError()` returned `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`) when trying to call `RegCreateKeyEx()` on a registry key where the running process had insufficient rights (in my case "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application"). **When starting the process with elevated privileges it succeeded.**

So maybe there could be a connection between error code 18 and UAC.